# How to not use WHERE in a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    c.ClaimId, c.Number, s.ClaimStatusId StatusId, c.ClaimedAmount, 
    c.Created AS Lodged, c.Updated,
    (u.UserName + '' + u.LastName) AS Creditor, 
    c.JobId, j.CompanyName AS JobName, 
    outcome.Approved AS ApprovedAmount, outcome.Rejected AS RejectedAmount,
    s.NormalizedName AS Status, type.Name AS Type, c.Version, c.RemarksCount
FROM 
    ClaimView c
INNER JOIN 
    ClaimType type ON c.TypeId = type.ClaimTypeId
LEFT JOIN 
    ClaimOutcome outcome ON outcome.ClaimId = c.ClaimId
INNER JOIN 
    Job j ON c.JobId = j.JobId
INNER JOIN 
    ApplicationUser u ON u.Id = c.CreatedBy
INNER JOIN 
    ClaimStatus s ON s.ClaimStatusId = c.StatusId
WHERE 
    c.CreatedBy = @userId 
    AND c.StatusId > 1
    AND c.IsDeleted = (CASE @isAdmin
                          WHEN 'False' THEN 0
                       END)
```

There's `@isAdmin` variable and I need to return date with @isAdmin IN (1,0) or to not use WHERE c.IsDeleted at all in case of `@isAdmin` is True. How I can implement it? That's my current code above.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause. (Better optimization.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
AND c.isDeleted = CASE WHEN @isAdmin = 'False' THEN 0 ELSE c.isDeleted END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `OR` to

- **either** check on the fact that `@isAdmin` is NOT `false` (alternatively you could/should check against `@isAdmin='true'`)
- **or** `c.isDeleted = 0`

But you will not need both conditions to be true.

```
...
WHERE 
c.CreatedBy = @userId 
AND c.StatusId > 1
AND (@isAdmin != 'False' OR c.IsDeleted = 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do. Might be overkill, but I think it's also more technically sound with the NULL handing:

```
    (
    AND (
        @isAdmin = 'False' 
    AND c.IsDeleted = 0
        )
     OR 
       (@isAdmin <> 'False'
    AND c.isDeleted IS NULL
       )
   )
```